# Photo gallery app with time stamps

Tags: iphone, ios, photos

In the default camera roll you can't see the time and date of your photos. Is there any app I can install to have my photos displayed like camera roll just with dates? It's quite annoying to search through over 2000 photos. A date selection or sorting would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PhotoCal](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photocal-sorting-photos-by/id474145607?mt=8) and [PhotoHistory](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photohistory/id473228750?mt=8) both allow you to browse photos by date. PhotoCal will also scan your Photostream.

Comment: Thanks dude, PhotoCal does the trick. Looks very nice and makes browsing Camera Roll aweseome. Bye bye default camera roll.

Answer (score 1):

[Photo Timestamps](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photo-timestamps/id839920232?mt=8) is a third party app that provides this information. It's not free, but it's also not $4.99. It's got a really clean, minimal interface (obligatory disclosure: I made it).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I love minimal interfaces. But I am befriended with PhotoCal already. The feature of the map is really nice. Also the categories for month or year are better than you just the whole camera roll since (at least on my phone) I have over 11'000 photos.